# Scrollbar value doesn't update after changing maximum (C# winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

If my scrollbar's value and maximum is both 500 and I change the maximum to 250 the value is still 500. When changing maximum I want value to automatically update.

Currently every time I change maximum I manually adjust value and it is quite tedious and repetitive.

Any solutions?

Comment: aside from refactoring your SetMaximum-code into a method that updates the value as well to stop the copy&paste? No sorry.

Comment: Post code that reproduces that.  Value changes on my computer when I change the Maximum value.

Comment: @LarsTech: Ah, sorry. What I meant to illustrate was that the value changes but it is an incorrect value. For example, if the LargeChange was 400 then after setting the maximum value to 250 the Value should not be Maximum. It should be Maximum - LargeChange + 1. Honestly it seems like a bug in the .Net Framework to me.. Also, obviously any values below zero should become zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround for this is to leave the maximum the same, and scale the scroll value in your application using a separate variable. For example, instead of changing the scrollbar maximum from 500 to 250, multiply the value of a variable, Q for this example, by .5. Then multiply the scrollbar.value by Q whenever you use it in the application.